# Setting div width to 100% minus certain amount of px

Tags: html, css, width

Have been searching the net for the past hours to find a solution to this, but couldn't find it, so here I am.

I need the width of the `div` to be `100%` minus the width of the `left div`.

So that the `div` to the left of it stays the same width (390px) but the other `div` adjusts its size depending on the resolution . I have found the solution where it has a fixed width `div` on both sides, but just cant figure this out.

[image]

Comment: You know, the orange box... TF2, Portal..

Comment: CSS has a new box model: The Orange Box Model

Comment: Sorry guys. Ment to add in a picture, but my reputation is not high enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="padder">

    </div><!-- .padder -->
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="padder">

    </div><!-- .padder -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#content {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}

div#content .padder {
    margin-left: 330px;
    padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}

div#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-right: -330px;
}
```

This will allow you to have a fixed sidebar width and a full width content area. I have used it many times and it works like a charm.

Comment: You cant have 2 ID's in HTML

Comment: Sure you can, you can't have two id's that are the same.

Answer (score 9):

This type of calculation isn't currently supported in CSS (certainly not in Chromium 12/Ubuntu 11.04), but there is a `calc()` function defined in CSS 3, which would allow for this kind of behaviour, using simple mathematical functions:

```
section {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em; border: solid 1px;
  width: calc(100%/3 - 2*1em - 2*1px);
}

p {
  margin: calc(1rem - 2px) calc(1rem - 1px);
  border: solid transparent; border-width: 2px 1px;
}
p:hover { border-color: yellow; }
```

(Above example taken directly from the [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc).)

My own (in-exhaustive) tests show:

```
+----------------+-------------------+
|  Browser       |  Ubuntu 11.04     |
+----------------+-------------------+
|  Chromium  12  |  Fails            |
|  Firefox  5    |  Fails            |
|  Opera  11.10  |  Fails            |
+----------------+-------------------+
```

The above results were obtained using the named browsers and a [css `calc()` demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UECgQ/1/), the code of which is below:

HTML:

```
<div id="box">This is the box.</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    width: calc(100% - 20%);
    background-color: #f90;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

(If anyone would like to run the above test in the browsers on their platform, and supply the results, or edit them in to this answer, that would be ***much*** appreciated.)

As pointed out, by [clairesuzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669044/clairesuzy), in comments:

> [Take] a look at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/calc) it does work in Firefox **if** you use `width: -moz-calc()` but that's about it ;)

And, indeed, in Firefox 5 (Ubuntu 11.04) it does work (the other vendor prefixes don't appear to do anything for Opera or Webkit, though; sadly): [Revised vendor-prefixed demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UECgQ/5/).

Reference:

- [CSS3 Values and Units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/).

Comment: take a look at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/calc) it does work in Firefox **if** you use `width: -moz-calc()` but that's about it ;)

Comment: So, a decade on I think you can update to say that calc() works and is probably the way to go in answering the title of the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="left">...</div>
<div id="content">...<br> more content</div>

#left {float: left; width: 390px; background: #f76922;}
#content {overflow: hidden; background: #eee;}
```

float the left div and make a new block formatting context out of the right div (overflow: hidden is one way to do that), that way it will take the remaining space

#### [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/YAuUY/)

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a way of doing this with straight up CSS right now in browsers other FireFox (see [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-calc)). You could use javascript to do the same, but I'd suggest rethinking your layout.

EDIT: actually IE 9 can handle it as well, see [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms531211.aspx). Yay for IE?

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. The thing is that the website has a twitter like layout. A left panel that can be scrolled and the right one that shows the content, so rethinking the layout is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not directly related to the question but I had a similar problem to arrange items in a list. The fixed-width element is to the right of each item. I've managed to solve this with the following approach. The idea is to balance a positive `padding-left` with a negative `margin-left`, while the width is set to `100%`:

```
.item {
  max-height: 40px;
}

.item-title {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -70px;
  padding-left: 65px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* This one should be fixed-width. */
.item-params {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
}
```