# Make full-width without setting `width`

Tags: css

I will simulate what i need to achieve.

for example, i want that **`#2`** took the whole space, remaining of `100% - 180px`.. how to achieve that?

[image]

p.s. seems `flexbox` is more supported over devices than `calc` - http://css3clickchart.com/#flexbox

Comment: This stack overflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601097/setting-div-width-to-100-minus-certain-amount-of-px) might help!

Comment: `display: table` on parent and `display: table-cell` on child, `flexbox`, `#2 {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; padding-left: 180px;`

Comment: you can use `flex` that will do it for you. You can use jQuery to work out that space and put it into your CSS that way. I dont know if css `calc` would work out the space

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35884883/3400962) answer in the link provided by @user3202670 is likely of particular interest

Comment: @justinas, no, that is quite quite mess. will look in other solutions posted here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox model as shown below. Adding `flex: auto;` will allow the right content to use remaining width.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
#left {
  width: 180px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
#right {
  flex: auto;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please, post BROWSER SUPPORT info about `flex`

Comment: Seems `flexbox` is more supported across devices, than `calc`

Answer (score 1):

Use css `calc`

Here with a example.. This might help:

```
.class {
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}​
```

Comment: please, post BROWSER SUPPORT info about `calc`

Comment: Check this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) or this [link](http://css3clickchart.com/#calc)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One simple way is below.

**1st way: Simple inline-block**

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;  
  }

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 180px;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
}
.main-content {
  display: inline-block; 
  background-color: green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">Main Content</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Fair warning though: In this case the .main-content will only take the space it needs, and will not actually be full width. So If you want to set background to it, you should actually set the backround to .container.

**2nd way:  Use calc for width**

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  position: relative;
  }

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 180px;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
}
.main-content {
  float: right;
  background-color: green;  
  width: calc(100% - 180px);
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">Main Content</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

**3rd way: use Flex**

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  display: flex;
  }

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 180px;
  height: 600px;
}
.main-content {
  background-color: green;
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="main-content">Main Content</div>
</div>
```

Flexbox is probably the nicest solution, but saidly old browsers don't support it.

**4th way of doing this is the oldfasioned way with faking tables:**

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2; 
  display: table;
  }

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 180px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.main-content {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>  
  <div class="main-content">Main Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: dont surprise, you might get into -~~~ on StkOvfl without realizing why.. read FAQ. I've upvoted though.

Comment: Thank you. My first day ever answering on SO. :)

Comment: This answer doesn't work. Add a background to main content and you'll see.

Comment: @Andrej good luck... however,, yes, see your answer again (i've updated), when you click `RUN SNIPPET` you will see that your code doesnt work.

Comment: I understand what you mean. 
The inline-block main-content takes only the space it needs.

Comment: @TJ I updated the answer to make it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: left` and `overflow: hidden`.

```css
aside {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background: beige;
}
article {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: brown;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  sidebar
</aside>
<article>
  content
</article>
```

Comment: `overflow:hidden` is not a good way